# Como fazer skins em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

### **Como faria skins em MVC?** onde o cliente(usuário) poderia escolher o skin (mudaria CSS, html, imagens, etc)?

OBS¹: O Skin seria para todas as páginas e cada cliente pode ter apenas 1 único skin. Mas eu teria uns 10 skins diferentes. Esses skins podem ser apenas um `css` diferente ou todo um site diferente.

OBS²: Imaginando que Somente a Controller pode ser igual para diferentes skins, Ex: `public ActionResult MostrarProduto()` vai retornar sempre a mesma coisa, somente a view ou o _Layout poderão ser diferentes.

Imagino de 3 formas, porém como não tenho experiência grande em MVC preciso de **FATOS** sobre vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma, claro que pode ser que nenhuma das 3 formas que imagino seja a melhor.

**1 - Filtros na controller:**

```
[VerificarSkin]
public ActionResult MostrarProduto()
{
```

**2 - Mudando o arquivo de Layout pela Controller ou View**

```
@{Layout = ViewBag.SkinAtual;}
```

**3- Mudando a Pasta da View** [[Vídeo explicando essa solução](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INgV_hKhhHY&list=WL)]

```
public ActionResult MostrarProduto()
{
    var skinAtual = "skin12";
     return View("../Views/" + skinAtual + "/Home/index.cshtml");
```

*Soluções:*

1 - Vantagens: Limpeza no código,

2 - Vantagens: aproveito a mesma view para todos os skins mudo apenas os layout, porém dai também pode ser uma desvantagem não pode personalizar a view?

3 - Vantagem: Posso mudar tudo, view e Layout, porém daria mais trabalho?

Cenário: Hoje tenho 300 clientes(usuários) onde cada um possui seu site, esses sites são compartilhados da minha ferramenta, onde ele pode escolher os skins (que são desde mudanças de cores a layout totalmente diferentes)

Comment: Sua ideia e trocar os skins por usuário, página, por permissão? Melhor, se escolher um skin será o mesmo para todas as páginas, ou eu posso escolher um para cada página, etc?

Comment: cada cliente teria apenas um único skin que seria aplicado para todas as páginas!

Comment: Quando você diz cliente você se refere a cada usuário que acessar o sistema ou seu sistema tem vários clientes e cada clientes pode ter vários usuários? Estou fazendo essas perguntas, pois o contexto de seu sistema, pode alterar alguns fatores. Mas, a terceira forma me parece inviável, até o momento.

Comment: boas perguntas vou atualizar a pergunta.  cliente = usuário.

Comment: Qual o método de autenticação, Identity?

Comment: nenhum, identifico o cliente pela url dele, assim sei qual site é qual ClienteId é. O site é de usuário anonimo, é um site e não um admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Não tem uma forma de falar qual é a melhor, pois vai depender do que você irá realmente precisar, explicarei melhor abaixo. Então, apontarei os pontos fortes e fracos dessas abordagens.

### Primeira Forma

A primeira forma, como você mesmo disse, deixa o código muito mais limpo, e sem redundância, pois irá criar um filtro para obter as a **Skin** necessária e retornar ao usuário. Creio que seria algo parecido com isso:

```
 public class LayoutInjecterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _masterName;
        public LayoutInjecterAttribute(string masterName)
        {
            _masterName = masterName;
        }
    
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
            var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            if (result != null)
            {
                result.MasterName = _masterName;
            }
        }
    }

[LayoutInjecter("_PublicLayout")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Fonte: [How do I specify different Layouts in the ASP.NET MVC 3 razor ViewStart file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161384/4843158)

Claro, aplicando as suas necessidades. A desvantagem desse método é que você não poderá modificar as `Views` com informações diferentes, ou seja, as `Views` serão as mesmas, o que irá mudar será o layout das mesmas.
**Obs.:** Se isso não for um problema, acho a melhor solução para seu caso.

### Segunda forma

Essa forma tem as mesmas desvantagens da primeira, você irá poder alterar somente o Layout, mas ainda conta com mais uma desvantagem, terá que criar a `ViewBag` a cada `Action`, pois o ciclo de vida da `ViewBag` não é utilizada em `Actions` distintas. Você pode fazer no `OnActionExecuted` ou `OnCreate` do controller, mas mesmo assim, terá que fazer em cada controler, ou na `View`, mas tenho certeza que você sabe que não "deve" fazer nada nela.

### Terceira forma

Essa é a forma que irá te dar mais trabalho para implementar, pois terá que replicar o código para cada **Skin** que possuir, e como disse que terá uns  10... Acho que você não quer esse trabalho todo.
Porém, se você precisa alterar algo, além do layout, em suas `Views`, essa será a única forma de conseguir fazer o que deseja.

Lembrando também, que você irá precisar obter a **Skin** em cada `View`, e isso pode não ser viável, dependendo da forma que busca esse **Skin**.

### Conclusão (Pessoal)

> Antes de concluir, devo lembrar que quando eu falo em "não mudar nada da `View`, me refiro à código que esteja naquela `View` em específico, mas se for algo que pode ser compartilhado para todos, você sempre terá o Shared `_Layout` para isso.

Das formas apresentadas, creio que a primeira seria a indicada. Além de não ter que reescrever o código, você conseguirá manipular cada `Action` diferentemente, caso deseje. Mas se precisa alterar algo em uma `View` ou outra, as duas primeiras formas não irá lhe servir.

Mas, dependendo do seu contexto, nada impede que você utilize mais de uma forma, utilizando a terceira somente onde for necessário.

Comment: a sua resposta me fez pensar, e acho que infelizmente a primeira opção não vai ser a melhor, pois ai eu teria que ter Views Iguais para todos os skins e creio que não irei consegui personaliza tanto o site apenas pela _Layout e css diferentes.

Comment: @Dorathoto Eu discordo. Com HTML/CSS você consegue personalizar o site todo, a primeira opção só não iria servir se você tiver comportamentos diferentes. Visual e até mesmo mostrar ou não algo, pode ser feito por apenas por CSS, caso queira.

Comment: Mas como eu disse, não tem como dar certeza sem conhecer o seu contexto. Então o que da para fazer é apenas falar um pouco sobre cada forma apresentada.

Comment: A forma mais correta é, de fato, a primeira. Não apenas especificar o nome fixo no código do atributo, mas também fazer um tipo de filtro cujo layout está de alguma forma associado ao usuário.

Comment: Acho q vou utilizar a primeira forma, porém nda impede de caso precise de uma view exclusiva ou crie uma nova ou use o terceiro método.